# how can I put one element under another in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a marker that is a svg image, and this is on a circle. 
until here everything is fine.

```
    var circle = svg.append("circle").attr("r",5).attr("cx",100).attr("cy",200).style("stroke","#FF0000");
    var circleBox = circle.node().getBBox();
    var widthMarker=100;
    var img = svg.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "marker.svg")
        .attr("width", widthMarker)
        .attr("height", widthMarker)
        .attr("x", circleBox.x + circleBox.width/2 - widthMarker/2)
        .attr("y",circleBox.y + circleBox.height/2 - widthMarker)
```

but then I am generating an animation of some circles in which they increase their size.

```
    function animation(){

      svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
      .data([1])
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
          .attr('cx', 100)
          .attr('cy', 200)
          .attr('r',5)
        .transition()
          .ease("linear")
          .duration(5000)
          .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
          .attr('r',50)
          .remove();
    }
    setInterval(function(){
      animation();
    },1000)
```

the problem is that I want that I am circles are below the marker, and currently all are above.

[image]

How can I fix it so that the animation of the circles are below the marker?
How can i fix it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/v4RlP8CASpZNxU2NmIdo?p=preview

thank you very much

It's not a good idea to create the "n" number of times. also in my real code to the marker I have assigned events of click, hover and others and creating it every time would hinder my functionality

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to add the appending of the image to the animation function:

```
 function animation(){

      svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
      .data([1])
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('opacity', 1)
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
          .attr('cx', 100)
          .attr('cy', 200)
          .attr('r',5)
        .transition()
          .ease("linear")
          .duration(5000)
          .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
          .attr('r',50)
          .remove();

     var img = svg.append("svg:image")
     .attr("xlink:href", "marker.svg")
     .attr("width", widthMarker)
     .attr("height", widthMarker)
     .attr("x", circleBox.x + circleBox.width/2 - widthMarker/2)
     .attr("y",circleBox.y + circleBox.height/2 - widthMarker)
    }
    setInterval(function(){
      animation();
    },1000)
```

every time you run the animation function, the blue circles are being drawn again. if you only draw the marker once, it will always be behind the circles. by adding the marker to the animation function, you ensure it's always placed on top of the circles every time they're redrawn.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I do not think it's a good idea to create the "n" number of times. also in my real code to the markerI have assigned events of click, hover and others and creating it every time would hinder my functionality

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/r7GaM7f7qwAwTP9N7C0W?p=preview

I'm just arranging the marker and the circles using groups i.e. `<g>`

```
var circles = svg.append('g').classed('circles', true);
var marker = svg.append('g').classed('marker', true);
var img = marker.append("svg:image")

function animation(){

  circles.selectAll('circle.emanting')
  ....
```

With this, the marker will always be on top of the circles. Hope this helps.